# How would I push a variable into an object value's name?

Tags: javascript

I am using a database and I want to store items that a user has in an object. How would I push a variable's value into a name of an object's value?

Code example:

```js
let item = 'test'
items.push({item: other})
```

Comment: In your specific case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names , or just `items.push({item});`, when you need to assign `other` to `item`.

Comment: What is `items` in this scenario and how would you like it to look after you've done the "push"? I'd like to understand your requirements but I don't

Answer (score 0):

You can set the key of an object to be the value of a variable like this:

```js
let item = 'test';
items.push({[item]: "foobar"});
```

Your result will look like this: `{test: "foobar"}`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
let item = "test";
let items = [];
items.push({
  [item]: "other"
})

console.log(items);
```